# Revoke Shared Access Signatures after initial access in Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage

I would like to essentially allow for one-time access to certain blob resources, requiring the user to check back with my server to get a new shared access signature before being able to access the resource again.

I have an implementation of this that I currently use, but I'm curious if there's something more ideal out there (particularly something already implemented in the Azure API that I missed).

Right now, a user can request the resource from the server. It validates their access to it, creates a unique hash in a database, directs the user to a link with that hash and the user loads the page. Once the page loads and they've completely downloaded the resource, I immediately invalidate the hash value in the database so it cannot be used again.

I know that Shared Access Signatures allow for time-based expiration, but do they allow for any sort of retrieval-count-based expiration, in that the user can completely download the resource and then the SAS invalidate itself?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One time use is not supported by SAS tokens. If you get a chance it would be great if you could add this request to our [Azure Storage User Voice Backlog](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage). I would also encourage other people with the same requirement to vote on that as wel.

Thanks

Jason